# ZK Java BandBox Image Click autoDrop + new ListItem into ListBox

Tags: java, listbox, zk

Hi guys i am very new to ZK framework i have 2 question i hope somebody can help me.

1). i have a Bandbox component create in Java Code my question is how can i react to a click in the Bandbox image without collapse the bandBox all i wanna do is call to another component on click event is this possible?

2). Guys i have a listBox with severals listItems[14 listCells per listItem]. i need to create a new ListItem using java code and in the new ListItem i need to access 2 cells where is the code i am using so far.

```
Student student = new Student();    
student.setAge(13); 
BindingListModelList modelList = (BindingListModelList) results.getModel();
if(modelList==null){
   modelList = new BindingListModelList(new ArrayList<Student>),false); 
   results.setModel(modelList);
}
modelList.add(student);
```

later i try to iterate over the listItem just created but i am receiving listItem.getChildren().size() == 1 all the time i expected all 14 children to handle two of them why is this? how can i add a  new listItem as well of receiving all the childrens?

Comment: hey guys i was able to solved the 2 one on the listBox method onAfterRender the ZK framework goes back to the zul renders the new added component and you can access it on onAfterRender method a event. but i am stuck on the 1 question can somebody help me.

Answer (score 0):

1)
As you see [here](http://www.zkoss.org/zkdemo/combobox/customizable_combobox) the `Bandbox` closes just on `bd.close()` which is not called on the navigation. Hope this helps to understand.

2) Post more **formatted** code from the program you tryed please.